# Implement Material UI as the documentation/demo page shows

Tags: material-ui

In fact I just want to implement the **left sidenav** under the AppBar in the same way as the documentation page of material-ui works.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just look at [the source code of the docs](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs), especially [AppLeftNav](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/AppLeftNav.jsx).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/material-ui-template) is a template that extracts the navigation and other chrome of the Material-UI docs site and allows you to easily add your own pages.